# VBA- automatically copy charts and tables to ppt

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I'm writing some code to automatically copy some of the charts from an excel to a ppt. The first issue that I am facing is with the variable declaration

```
Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
```

The error is "User defined-type not defined". Just to let you know I'm pretty new to this VBA, so some descriptive comments would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is because your powerpoint variables want to be defined as objects, and the objects set to be powerpoint applications later on.

```
Sub ChartX2P()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then 
MsgBox "Hey, please select a chart first." 
Exit Sub 
End If

If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then _ 
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'this will create a new powerpoint for your chart
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'this will open an old powerpoint up, just change "File address" to the address
'Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="FileAddress")

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

mySlide.Shapes.Paste
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

myShape.Left = 200
myShape.Top = 200

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is taken from [here](https://www.goodly.co.in/copy-chart-from-excel-to-powerpoint-using-vba/), but it looks pretty straightforward, anything you can't get from the site let me know